# How to make treeview presenting generic xml editable?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview

Right now i have treeview that is presenting generic xml:

```
 <TreeView Name="myTreeView"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewTemplate}"/>


 <MyApp.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="xmlValueBrush"/>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="xmAttributeBrush"/>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="DarkMagenta" x:Key="xmlTagBrush"/>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="xmlMarkBrush"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="attributeTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Margin="3,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmAttributeBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="=&quot;" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlValueBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="&quot;" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsManipulationEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="treeViewTemplate" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::node()}">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,0,0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" 
                           x:Name="startTag"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Margin="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    x:Name="xmlTag"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource xmlTagBrush}"/>

                <ItemsControl 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource attributeTemplate}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>

                <TextBlock Text="&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" 
                           x:Name="endTag"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeType}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <xmlNodes:XmlNodeType>Text</xmlNodes:XmlNodeType>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding InnerText}" 
                            TargetName="xmlTag"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" 
                            TargetName="xmlTag"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" 
                            TargetName="startTag"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" 
                            TargetName="endTag"/>

                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasChildNodes}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="/&gt;" TargetName="endTag"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </MyApp.Resources>
```

In code-behind xml is binded to treeview like this:

```
myTreeView.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding); //binding is binded XMLDataProvider
```

How can i make this treeview editable. For example if i have this xml:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to make values inside tags like: Tove, Jani, Reminder editable.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting [`treeView.LabelEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.labeledit(v=vs.110).aspx) to true:

```
treeView.LabelEdit = true;
```

when this is set, you should be able to edit the node text by clicking it. You can also use

```
treeView.Nodes[0].BeginEdit();
```

to edit a specific node. The above code will start editing the root node.

Comment: I tried that but i weirdly i don't have those properties in my treeview, the 3 top one are SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath.

Comment: Sorry about that, I assumed you were using WinForms. Not sure how to do that in wpf, unfortunately...